# I can't drag fields from joint datasets into a grid or table while using BIRT

Tags: mysql, eclipse, birt, join

I just started using BIRT to create reports and have stumbled upon a problem that I just can't get a way around. I'm using Eclipse Luna, MySql database and BIRT downloaded from this [link](http://download.eclipse.org/birt/update-site/4.4).

The problem is that when I create a joint dataset I am not able to drag the fields under the joint dataset into the report (in grids or tables). Could you please help me figure out a way around this? Thanks!

Comment: The same is working for me. Are you sure your tables are not already bound to another dataset when you try to drag these fields? May be you could post a simple .rptdesign showing the issue, based on the sample database "classicmodels"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution to the problem. Not exactly a solution, more of a workaround. Right clicking on the field in the data set and clicking on "Insert in layout" inserts the field in the report and it can then be dragged to the desired position.

Comment: You should mark this answer as accepted so others will know you are no longer looking for a solution.